# gtk, regexp: how to get groups value

Tags: regex, gtk

I have following code:

```
gchar **split = g_strsplit(str, "\n", 0);
gchar **pointer = NULL;
GRegex *line_regex = NULL;
GMatchInfo *info = NULL;
line_regex = g_regex_new("^.*:(\\d+):.*$", 0, 0, NULL);

gtk_list_store_clear(store);
gtk_list_store_clear(store);
for (pointer = split; *pointer; pointer++)
    if (strlen(*pointer)){
        gchar *word = "";
        if (line_regex && g_regex_match(line_regex, *pointer, 0, &info)){
            if (g_match_info_matches(info)){
                word = g_match_info_fetch(info, 0);
            }
        }
        gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(store, NULL, -1, 0, word, 1, *pointer, -1);
    }
```

I would like to get value inside the group, which means for following string:

```
some-test:56:some-other-text
```

I would like to get 56. I have no idea how `gtk` works, so I am a little blind here and I haven't found anything in docs. In `python` I would use `groups` methods, so here I would need something similar. Could you advise me how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found useful information at gnome.org's [g-match-info-fetch page](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.29/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html#g-match-info-fetch) which indicates that `g_match_info_fetch(info, 0)` returns the whole match, which for your `^ ... $` regex is the whole line.  The code shown below (which is like your code, except I replaced `gtk_list_store` stuff with a printf) illustrates that `g_match_info_fetch(info, 1)` returns the field you want.  The code displays the following 3 lines:

```
info 1 =   56,   info 0 = a-test:56:some-other-text
No match in b-test:283B:some-other-text
info 1 =  718,   info 0 = c-test:718:some-other-text
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(void) {
  char *str = "a-test:56:some-other-text\nb-test:283B:some-other-text\nc-test:718:some-other-text\n";
  gchar **split = g_strsplit(str, "\n", 0);
  gchar **pointer = NULL;
  GRegex *line_regex = NULL;
  GMatchInfo *info = NULL;
  line_regex = g_regex_new("^.*:(\\d+):.*$", 0, 0, NULL);

  for (pointer = split; *pointer; pointer++)
    if (strlen(*pointer)) {
      if (line_regex && g_regex_match(line_regex, *pointer, 0, &info)) {
        if (g_match_info_matches(info)) {
          printf ("info 1 = %4s,   info 0 = %s\n",
              g_match_info_fetch(info, 1),
              g_match_info_fetch(info, 0));
        }
      } else
        printf ("No match in %s\n", *pointer);
    }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Correct, except this leaks memory: you have to free the return values from `g_match_info_fetch()` and call `g_match_info_unref()` on the match info object within the `for` loop. You also have to unref the regex at the end of the program, but that's not so crucial here.

Comment: Glib manual says GMatchInfo is not thread safe. does it mean g_regex_match (regex, message, 0, &match_info); is also not threadsafe.?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya, I don't know whether what you mention is threadsafe.  However, it is true that g_regex_match can be used threadsafely.  Quoting [a gnome.org page](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html):  “Creating and manipulating the same GRegex structure from different threads is not a problem as GRegex does not modify its internal state between creation and destruction, on the other hand GMatchInfo is not threadsafe.” Also see numerous examples in a [marc.info page](http://marc.info/?l=gtk-devel&m=117404810006026)

Comment: g_regex_match takes GMatchInfo as argument and sets it. so if GMatchInfo is not threadsafe, g_regex_match also should not be thread safe.